# Returning String from a int function

Tags: java

My question is simple, im having trouble on returning my value(sorry im a beginner)

```
int modulo10(String a, String b) {
String res;
int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
x = (x+y)%y;

res = Integer.toString(x);
return res;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return a String? Either return x or change the return type to String.

Comment: You're returning a ``String`` when your method declares a return type of ``int``. Change the return type to ``String`` and it will compile.

Comment: Why not `return x;`?

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strongly typed language. From the line `String res;`, `res` is a String variable, but you are trying to put an `Integer` inside.

As `x` is an `Integer` and contains the value you want to return, you can just `return x` instead.

You can convert an `Integer` into an `int`, because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), and you can do the reverse because of unboxing. More generally, you can convert any primitive type into its wrapper class (`Integer` for `int`, `Boolean` for `boolean`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. You declared that your method returns an `int` and you try to return a `String` - pick one. Either change your method to return `String` or just `return x;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a string from a function having int return type .

```
int modulo10 (int a, int b){
int x;

x = (a+b)%b;

return x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the return type of the method

```
int modulo10(String a, String b) {
```

into

```
String modulo10(String a, String b) {
```

or simply return your int x without converting it into String res, depends what you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

If String a,b conatains any non-numeric value it will give ParseException.
And As your method return int value,you are returning string value.So Java will throw exception.Hope you will get your point.

Answer (score 0):

change your data type from int to String